# Fancybox Image Gallery + Blobstore

Tags: google-app-engine, fancybox, blobstore

For retrieving image from blobstore, I usually do the following and it works:

```
<img src="/image?blob_key={{ blob_key }}"></img>
```

As far as I read about fancybox and personally tried it:

```
$("a[rel=photo_collections]").fancybox({
'transitionIn'      : 'none',
'transitionOut'     : 'none',
});

<a rel="photo_collections" href="/image/photo.png"> Photos </a>
<a rel="photo_collections" href="/image/photo2.png"> Photos </a>
```

The above image gallery works if I have images in the folder.

So, my question is what if I want to retrieve images from Blobstore instead of folder?

So, I tried following it doesn't work:

```
$("a[rel=photo_collections]").fancybox({
'transitionIn'      : 'none',
'transitionOut'     : 'none',
});

<a rel="photo_collections" href="/image/photo.png"> Photos </a>
<a rel="photo_collections" href="/image/photo2.png"> Photos </a>

// This part, the fancybox works but it doesn't display the image correctly. All it shows were some sort of binary data instead of image
<a rel="photo_collections" href="/image?blob_key={{ blob_key }}"
```

**Hence, I've two main questions here:**

1. How to solve the problem mentioned above ?
2. If I wish to do something like Google Plus/Facebook Photo Viewer, where while viewing the images, user is able to make comments. Does this require HTML content gallery instead of just images gallery since I need more HTML form control?

**EDIT**

Following is the handler to serve the image retrieved from Blobstore:

```
class RemoteDisplayImageHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
    def get(self):

    blob_key = self.request.GET.get('blob_key', None)
    blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(blob_key)

    logging.debug('blob_key=%s', blob_key)
    logging.debug('blob_info=%s', blob_info)

    if not blob_info:
        raise Exception('Blob Key does not exist')

    self.send_blob(blob_info)
```

Comment: What you got after this URL? binary content of your image? what mime-type?

Comment: Yeah...those like with "?4567898CDEFGHcdefghhi......"

Comment: so, the problem that it have invalid content-type?

Comment: Yea..Apparently..It displays whole bunch of numbers and characters instead of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using alternative:

```
            options.push({
                    'href'  : 'image_url',
                    'class' : 'iframe'
                });

            $.fancybox(options, {
                'padding'           : 0,
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none',
                'type'              : 'image',
                'changeFade'        : 0
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your image handler is returning the wrong content type. Make sure you set the `Content-Type` header correctly in the response.

Comment: What Content-Type shall I set? I've edited my question to include the handler class. As I've explained, when I used <img> element to request the image, it works fine. So, if I'm using <a> element, what shall I do to make it work?

Comment: @MrCooL `image/png` if it's a PNG, `image/jpeg` if it's a JPEG, etc. If you uploaded the file using the standard blobstore upload handler, this should already be set - you can confirm with wget or your browser's dev tools.

Comment: Did you mean this way, <a rel="photo_collections" href="/image/png?blob_key={{ blob_key }}"

Yes, I used the standard blobstore upload handler way to store it..and I stored the blobstore key in the datastore..

Comment: Sorry...I didn't mean to ask too many questions...But I'm really confused with the Blobstore usage...Besides, I'm still new to web development...Hope that you can give me a more clear example...

Comment: @MrCool, no changing the URL will have no effect - you need to set the mimetype in the response headers of the request that serves up your images. First, though, you should use your browser's developer tools to see what mimetype it's being served up as currently.